# Correctly place geom_text labels in forest plot with "fill" parameter in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create annotated publication-ready forest plots comparing different models. How do I ensure that the labels are placed above and tight against the corresponding error bars and do not overlap?

I've also asked the RStudio community for help on March 9, 2022. [Here is a link to the original post.](https://community.rstudio.com/t/correctly-place-geom-text-labels-in-forest-plot-with-fill-parameter-in-ggplot2/131243)

Thank you for your help!

Here is what I tried:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(knitr)
#> Warning: package 'knitr' was built under R version 4.1.2
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~term, ~n_obs,   ~estimate,   ~conf.low,  ~conf.high,            ~ci,    ~p.value,  ~group,
    "A",   101L,        0.62, 0.497390282, 0.797429694, "0.50 to 0.80", 0.000123131,   "One",
    "A",    65L,        0.57, 0.468908017, 0.693458768, "0.47 to 0.69", 1.83138e-08,   "Two",
    "A",    36L,        0.81, 0.623804568, 1.064787867, "0.62 to 1.06", 0.133680272, "Three",
    "B",    26L,        0.87, 0.665400224,   1.1489204, "0.67 to 1.15", 0.335220534,   "One",
    "B",    16L,        1.02, 0.755403541, 1.388386542, "0.76 to 1.39", 0.878076678,   "Two",
    "B",    10L,        0.29, 0.091804704, 0.978289216, "0.09 to 0.98", 0.045898245, "Three",
    "C",   143L,        0.90, 0.749027775, 1.089930323, "0.75 to 1.09", 0.289131987,   "One",
    "C",    82L,        1.02,  0.82229374, 1.286815562, "0.82 to 1.29", 0.804649191,   "Two",
    "C",    61L,        0.61, 0.359730119, 1.036462037, "0.36 to 1.04",  0.06765433, "Three"
  )
data %>% kable()
```

| term | n_obs | estimate | conf.low | conf.high | ci | p.value | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 101 | 0.62 | 0.4973903 | 0.7974297 | 0.50 to 0.80 | 0.0001231 | One |
| A | 65 | 0.57 | 0.4689080 | 0.6934588 | 0.47 to 0.69 | 0.0000000 | Two |
| A | 36 | 0.81 | 0.6238046 | 1.0647879 | 0.62 to 1.06 | 0.1336803 | Three |
| B | 26 | 0.87 | 0.6654002 | 1.1489204 | 0.67 to 1.15 | 0.3352205 | One |
| B | 16 | 1.02 | 0.7554035 | 1.3883865 | 0.76 to 1.39 | 0.8780767 | Two |
| B | 10 | 0.29 | 0.0918047 | 0.9782892 | 0.09 to 0.98 | 0.0458982 | Three |
| C | 143 | 0.90 | 0.7490278 | 1.0899303 | 0.75 to 1.09 | 0.2891320 | One |
| C | 82 | 1.02 | 0.8222937 | 1.2868156 | 0.82 to 1.29 | 0.8046492 | Two |
| C | 61 | 0.61 | 0.3597301 | 1.0364620 | 0.36 to 1.04 | 0.0676543 | Three |

```r
data %>% rowwise() %>%
  ## plot with variable on the y axis and estimate (OR) on the x axis
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = term, color = group), alpha = .7, width = .7) +

  ## show the estimate as a point
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(.9), size = 1.5) +
        
  
  ## add in an error bar for the confidence intervals
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), position = position_dodge(.9), size = 1) +
        
        ## add in labels     
  geom_text(aes( label = paste0(estimate, " (", ci, ") n = ", n_obs), x = estimate, y = term),color = "black", position = position_dodge(.9), show.legend = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE) +

  ggplot2::theme_bw() +
  scale_colour_grey() +

  ## show where OR = 1 is for reference as a dashed line
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Maybe `vjust = -1` in `geom_text` does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a grouping variable to the text layer, since you remove its dodging variable by specifying `color = 'black'` outside `aes`.

Also, you can use `vjust` to move the text above the bars:

```r
data %>% rowwise() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = term, color = group), alpha = .7, width = .7) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(.9), size = 1.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), 
                position = position_dodge(.9), size = 1) +  
  geom_text(aes( label = paste0(estimate, " (", ci, ") n = ", n_obs), 
                 x = estimate, y = term, group = group), color = "black", 
            position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = -0.4,
            show.legend = FALSE, check_overlap = FALSE) +
  ggplot2::theme_bw() +
  scale_colour_grey() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed") +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image]